# Number Gusser in c++ using function and midpoint

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a code for number gusser using funcitons:
The playOneGame function should have a return type of void. It should implement a complete guessing game on the range of 1 to 100.
The shouldPlayAgain function should have a boolean return type. It should prompt the user to determine if the user wants to play again, read in a character, then return true if the character is a ‘y’, and otherwise return false.
In addition, you should implement the helper functions getUserResponseToGuess, and getMidpoint. They should be invoked inside your playOneGame function.
getUserResponseToGuess. This function should prompt the user with the phrase “is it ? (h/l/c): “  with the value replacing the token . It should return a char. The char should be one of three possible values: ‘h’, ‘l’, or ‘c’.  It should have the following signature:
char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)
getMidpoint. This function should accept two integers, and it should return the midpoint of the two integers. If there are two values in the middle of the range then you should consistently chose the smaller of the two. It should have the following signature:
int getMidpoint(int low, int high)
I start withit but I still can't get the logic of it.This what I have so far.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

 void playOneGame;
 char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess);
 int getMidpoint ( int low, int high);

int main() {
do
 {
 playOneGame();
} while (shouldPlayAgain());
return 0;
}
void playOneGame
{
int a = 100;


cout << "\nGuess a number between 1 and 100. " <<endl;
getUserResponseToGuess ( a);

 }


char getUserResponseToGuess(int guess)
{
while (true)
{
int guess = getMidpoint(minimum, maximum);
std::cout << "\nIs it [h]igher/[l]ower/[e]qual to " << guess << "? ";
char answer;
if (!(std::cin >> answer))
{
    std::cerr << "error reading user input, program exiting\n";
    exit(1);
}
if (answer == 'h')
    minimum = guess + 1;
else if (answer == 'l')
    maximum = guess - 1;
else if (answer == 'e')
{
    std::cout << "Well, isn't that nice.\n";
    return;
}
if (minimum > maximum)
{
    std::cerr << "hey, you lied to me!\n";
    exit(1);
}
}
}

int getMidpoint ( int low, int high)
{

int mid;

mid = (low + high) / 2;

return mid;

}
```

Comment: Review: this looks like a homework problem?  Ask something specific if you're having issues with your code, and format your question in  readable steps.

Comment: You haven't said specifically what problem it has when running, and what you've tried to do to fix it, what you expected, what you observed....  If you just want a general code review, click the grey triangle next to the StackOverflow logo at the top left of this site and pick "Code Review" - add a question there.

Comment: @myninjaname I can't get the logic, to be specific how to update the range each time so i can pass it to midpoint funtion and return with the int

Comment: @TonyD this simple of output 
Guess a number between 1 and 100.
Is it 50?  (h/l/c): h
Is it 75?  (h/l/c): h
Is it 88?  (h/l/c): l
Is it 81?  (h/l/c): c
Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): y
Guess a number between 1 and 100.
Is it 50?  (h/l/c): l
Is it 25?  (h/l/c): h
Is it 37?  (h/l/c): c
Great! Do you want to play again? (y/n): n

Comment: You can't call it like this: `getMidpoint ( a, guess); ret= getMidpoint;`... try `ret = getMidpoint(a, guess);`.  Separately, it's not practical to have nested `if` statements for each guess... there are too many paths of higher and lower before answers are found.  Instead, you should have a `for` or `while` loop or use recursion to keep guessing.

Comment: @TonyD cool, how about the range how to update it each time

Comment: There are a lot of errors in this code, several simple changes should get you something that will compile.

Comment: @MohamedAyadi: well, I'd keep two variables with properly descriptive names - `minimum` and `maximum`... at first they'll be 1 and 100, then in each iteration of the loop (that you need to add) set a higher `minimum` or lower `maximum` until you've narrowed down the range to find the answer.

Comment: @TonyD can you give me an example for for loop that explain what u meant please I knew what you mean but I can't get the logic

Comment: @MohamedAyadi there's some code below which I hope helps....

Answer (score 1):

The guessing loop should loop something like this:

```
while (true)
{
    int guess = getMidpoint(minimum, maximum);
    std::cout << "\nIs it [h]igher/[l]ower/[e]qual to " << guess << "? ";
    char answer;
    if (!(std::cin >> answer))
    {
        std::cerr << "error reading user input, program exiting\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (answer == 'h')
        minimum = guess + 1;
    else if (answer == 'l')
        maximum = guess - 1;
    else if (answer == 'e')
    {
        std::cout << "Well, isn't that nice.\n";
        return;
    }
    if (minimum > maximum)
    {
        std::cerr << "hey, you lied to me!\n";
        exit(1);
    }
}
```